# image_tag not working for all images the same way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, apache

I have a rails app (following Agile Web Development with Rails 4 -book) I'm trying to get hosted on apache+passenger+mysql -configuration. Now I've gotten most of the stuff working, but some of the images are not working correctly. For some images, `image_tag "logo.jpg"` for example the output in the html is correctly `<img alt="Logo" src="/assets/logo-0f0773ff0a4264e6952c45931e50f722.png" />`.

However, for another image (located in the very same folder), the html that comes out looks like this `<img alt="Cs" src="/images/cs.jpg" />`. This comes from a loop like this:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_image') %>
<% end %>
```

The `image_url` of the first product is `cs.jpg`. To make things even more curious, if I run `rails console` and run this command

`pry(main)> ApplicationController.helpers.image_tag Product.first.image_url, class: 'list_image'`, I actually get the expected output of

`=> "<img alt=\"Cs\" class=\"list_image\" src=\"/assets/cs-e1864c1128d6c90247bcd9275228284b.jpg\" />"`

So how is it possible that the same helper method gives me different results with the (at least seemingly) same invocation?

Comment: Have you run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and reloaded the server?

Comment: Yes I have (a few times).

Comment: Confirm for me that `cs.jpg` exists in `/assets/images` in the source before you deploy. Is that true?

Comment: yep, `app/assets/images/cs.jpg` to be exact

Comment: I still don't know why this happened, but after deploying the very same app via capistrano, everything seems to be working.